# Does Nautilus Support Undo/Redo for Basic File Operations

Tags: nautilus

I was wondering if Nautilus has undo/redo features for basic file operations. To be specific, I want to be able to undo moving, renaming or deleting a file.

Comment: It is the file manager's (which is Nautilus) job to undo or redo file operations and not Unity.

Answer (score 5):

That's something that would be handled by Nautilus. I don't have it installed so I can't check (currently running Xubuntu) but I don't believe they have implemented it yet.  [They are working on adding that feature](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/05/default-nautilus-will-soon-look-lot.html), and I believe [Nautilus Elementary](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/01/nautilus-elementary-simplified-nautilus.html) already has it. You could also use another file manager like [4pane](http://www.4pane.co.uk/) that already has undo/redo

[Dolphin](http://dolphin.kde.org/) also has undo/redo

Comment: I can confirm that Nautilus Elementary has it, but I had no idea that regular Nautilus doesn't come with these options.

Answer (score 2):

Nautilus just recently got this feature to undo changes in GNOME 3.4. You can read about this feature in this [bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=648658.) which discussed the feature before implementing it.

But, what this means is that you can only undo your changes if you are using 12.04 as the Nautilus in older versions do not have this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Tried searching for undo option with an out-of-the box 11.04 Unity, seems like if you keep it stock, there is no option to undo changes.